# Replacing span text within href tag

Tags: javascript, tags, href, html

can anyone help me i'm trying to change the text of a span tag, within a href tag.  The following code seems to work in Jsfiddle but not on my site?

http://jsfiddle.net/cqQt4/

HTML:

```
<a href="#pdpTab1"><span>Product Description</span></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('a[href^="#pdpTab1"]').addClass('productdesc');
$(function() {
    $("a.productdesc").each(function(index,el){
        $(el).text('Descripción del producto');
    }); 
});
```

I have used similar method for div and a class an they work perfectly both in Jsfiddle and my site! Any suggestions on other ways i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are not adding the class to the `<a>` element correctly.

Your jQuery code is looking for this `$("a.productdesc")`, I suggest changing the first line of code to inside the `$(function() {`.

Btw your code is missing a **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**, you can use like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href^="#pdpTab1"]').addClass('productdesc'); // you should add this class to the html instead.
    $("a.productdesc").each(function(index,el){
        $(el).find('span').text('Descripción del producto');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: The class gets set in the first line of the example, I'm assuming that happens before the lookup?

Answer (score 2):

You have to select the span inside the `<a>`-element:

```
$(el).find('span').text('Descripción del producto');
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use children metdod,so try this;

```
var aTag=$('a href["#pdpTab1"]');

$(aTag).each(function(incoming,index)
{
$(this).children('span').text('something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct only, try putting `$('a[href^="#pdpTab1"]').addClass('productdesc');` inside `$(function(){});`

```
  $(function() {
    $('a[href^="#pdpTab1"]').addClass('productdesc');
    $("a.productdesc").each(function(index,el){
     $(el).text('Descripción del producto');
   }); 
 });
```

you can keep the span if you use `.find('span')` else the span will be gone.

http://jsfiddle.net/cqQt4/1/